# How to segment a scanned Page so that it can be fed into an OCR

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ocr

I have an OCR that can read a given character. Now I want to build something that can take a scanned document and convert it into text. The problem is how do I segment each character? I know this can be done manually but how to automate it? I know that segmenting italics is different but since I want to go step by step I am considering normal fonts.

Comment: "I have an OCR that can read a given character" What do you mean you have an ocr? OCR stands for optical character recognition.